# How to find a pair of parameters minimizing the value of a scalar function taking 4 input arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, optimization, scipy

I have defined a python-function taking four inputs and which returns a scalar. The first two inputs are vectors, while the last two inputs are scalars.
For given two vectors (first two inputs), I want to find the values of `y0` and `y1`, which minimize the function. What is the best way of doing it?

Here is the sample code of the function:

```
def f(y_,y,y0,y1):
    xy1 = [i*y1 for i in range(len(y_))]
    diff = [(y_[i] + y0 + xy1[i] - y[i])**2 for i in range(len(y_))]
    return sum(diff)

y_ = [x**2 + 1.4 for x in range(-10,11,1)]
y= [x**2 + 1. for x in range(-10,11,1)]
x = [3*i for i in range(len(y_))]
print('x:',x)
print('y_:',y_,'\n','y:',y)
print('f:',f(y_,y,0,0))
```

Output:

```
x: [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60]
y_: [101.4, 82.4, 65.4, 50.4, 37.4, 26.4, 17.4, 10.4, 5.4, 2.4, 1.4, 2.4, 5.4, 10.4, 17.4, 26.4, 37.4, 50.4, 65.4, 82.4, 101.4] 
y: [101.0, 82.0, 65.0, 50.0, 37.0, 26.0, 17.0, 10.0, 5.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0, 17.0, 26.0, 37.0, 50.0, 65.0, 82.0, 101.0]
f: 3.360000000000019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your function wrapped in a [python lambda](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20an%20anonymous%20function,x%2C%20y%3A%20x%20%2B%20y) so it takes a single vector argument and can be passed to scipy.minimize.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(y_,y,y0,y1):
    xy1 = [i*y1 for i in range(len(y_))]
    diff = [(y_[i] + y0 + xy1[i] - y[i])**2 for i in range(len(y_))]
    return sum(diff)

y_ = [x**2 + 1.4 for x in range(-10,11,1)]
y= [x**2 + 1. for x in range(-10,11,1)]
x = [3*i for i in range(len(y_))]
print('x:',x)
print('y_:',y_,'\n','y:',y)
print('f:',f(y_,y,0,0))



toMinimize = lambda x: f(y_,y, x[0], x[1])
res = minimize(toMinimize, (0, 0))

print(res.message)
print('optimizal position: ',res.x)
print('minimal value: ',res.fun)
```

This gives the following output.

```
x: [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60]
y_: [101.4, 82.4, 65.4, 50.4, 37.4, 26.4, 17.4, 10.4, 5.4, 2.4, 1.4, 2.4, 5.4, 10.4, 17.4, 26.4, 37.4, 50.4, 65.4, 82.4, 101.4] 
 y: [101.0, 82.0, 65.0, 50.0, 37.0, 26.0, 17.0, 10.0, 5.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0, 17.0, 26.0, 37.0, 50.0, 65.0, 82.0, 101.0]
f: 3.360000000000019
Optimization terminated successfully.
optimizal position:  [-4.00000011e-01 -5.25897060e-09]
minimal value:  1.0614222972874884e-13
```

Answer (score 1):

Just posting an alternative solution for "completeness":

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(params,y_,y):
    y0,y1 = params
    xy1 = [i*y1 for i in range(len(y_))]
    diff = [(y_[i] + y0 + xy1[i] - y[i])**2 for i in range(len(y_))]
    return sum(diff)

y_ = [(x-3)**2 + 1.4 for x in range(-10,11,1)]
y= [x**2 + 1. for x in range(-10,11,1)]
x = [3*i for i in range(len(y_))]
print('x:',x)
print('y_:',y_,'\n','y:',y)
print('f:',f([0,0],y_,y))

y0 = 0.
y1 = 0.
minimize(f, [y0, y1], args=(y,y_))
```